# Convert simplified discrete area to borders polygon

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, border

suppose that I have discrete map, on this map appears country represented by color blue:

[image: country without borders]

country area is always coherent.

Now I want to extract borders from it:

[image: country with borders]

So:

- I have a list of unordered tiles of country, in this case: (3,3), (4,3), (4,4)...
- I want to extract ordered sequence of borders, in this case: ((2,2),(3,2)), ((3,2),(4,2)),.... where ((x1,y1),(x2,y2)) means that beggining of border starts in (x1,y1) and ends in (x2,y2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Firstly find the rightest point in your matrix no matter how tall. If you finded points with same x, choose arbitrarily.
2. Find all borders of this point.
3. If you have a point bordering on
   top, go for it, else go to the
   right, else go to the bottom, else
   go to the left, go to the direction
   where have border with other point,
   always in that order. If encountered
   point is the initial point, go to
   step 7, else go to the next step.
4. store the two points (principal
   point, encountered point) in your
   path.
5. Now the encountered point is
   principal point.
6. Go to step 2
7. the path contains what you want